# How do I select my JDK version in CloudBees Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, cloudbees, java-6

I want to use 1.6 and I've configured it as my JDK version for my Jenkins job, but it keeps building with Java 7 instead. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: do u have a link or reference where it says its a bug. I am looking for one.

Comment: I used a support ticket in the CloudBees help desk as reference. I don't think anyone else can see it without the proper permissions, but here's the link: https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/agent/#/tickets/12333

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is an existing Jenkins bug, but that you can work around it by installing the Environment Injector Plugin and manually setting your path with inject env variable:

```
PATH=/opt/jdk/jdk1.6.latest/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

Configuration mismatch on jenkins global configuration. JDK installation name is "JDK 6" but is tied to a pre-installed JDK 7. Can't tell how this happened.